# How does an encryption algorithm actually encrypt data

Tags: encryption, public-key-encryption, encryption-symmetric, encryption-asymmetric

What I want to know, is not how encryption works, what are keys etc <- I kinda got that, like how DH works, and I did learn asymmetric keys a while back, but I'll probably need to refresh on that.

What I want to know is how does the key turn some plaintext like "HELLO" into ciphertext such as "MQPCT"

What actually happens to the string during the process, does each character get turned into a number somehow? That sort of thing

Hopefully my question makes sense

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing. You start by saying that you're not asking how encryption works, then reference a non-encryption algorithm (DH), and then ask how encryption works. The answer depends entirely on the algorithm. Different encryption algorithms encrypt in completely different ways. For example, no modern algorithm would ever convert "HELLO" into "MQPCT" (there's only 1 in 100k keys that would do that, so you would know immediately it's not AES). That's something you would expect from older algorithm like the Enigma engine. So what algorithm do you mean?

Comment: (If you're interested in modern ciphers like AES, do see mti2935's answer. The wikipedia link is certainly a reasonable start.)

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question about what happens to the string during the process - the string is decoded into bits, then the bits are encrypted.

Most modern encryption protocols ultimately use AES symmetric encryption to encrypt the message, using a secret key shared by both the sender of the message and the recipient.  The message is broken up into blocks of 128 bits (and usually padded), then the AES algorithm is used to encrypt these bits.  For information on how AES does this, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard.